How to migrate Pacts arrayEachLike to Lambda DSL
I am currently in the process of migrating multiple pacts to the Lambda DSL (I LOVE it <3).
I am struggling to find the right substitute for arrayEachLike(examples: Int).
My example:
@Pact(consumer = CONSUMER, provider = PROVIDER)
  RequestResponsePact pact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
    return builder
        .uponReceiving("get cities")
        .method("GET")
        .path("/rest/cities")
        .willRespondWith()
        .status(200)
        .body(
            arrayEachLike(2)
                .stringType("name", "Berlin")
        )
        .toPact()
  }

I tried this, but I cannot give the number of examples I want to have here:
.body(
  LambdaDsl.newJsonArray { rootArray: LambdaDslJsonArray ->
    rootArray.`object` { object ->
      object.stringType("name", "Berlin")
    }
  }.build()
)

What can I do instead to be able to put a number of examples in, but not a min/max size?
